Any way for batch conversion from JPG to DDS with DXT1 compression
I have an "file.jpg" image, I open it with GIMP, then go to "File", "Export As...", choose "DDS image". I choose the compression - BC1/DXT1, other options are default, and get the "file.dds" of size 128 KB.
I could do the same with Photoshop saving the "file.jpg" as DDS file (I installed DDS plugin for Photoshop), and I get the "file.dds" of size 128 KB.
I have a directory which contains several subdirectories each of which contains several JPG pictures. All what I need is to export all these JPG images to DDS format and get the results the same as if they were received if I exported them manually one by one as I've written above. The all exported DDS files should have names the same as their input JPG files. Also, it would be nice to delete all input JPG files after conversion.
I've tried several ways:

ImageMagick BAT script for Windows CMD. But it converts my JPG image differently, and I get output DDS files of size 170 KB.
XnConvert. It works fine, but output DDS have DXT5 compression and size 256 KB.
Also, I've tried ImBatch, Converseen (and something else), and I couln't give the results like after GIMP or Photoshop conversion.

I've tried to create an action for Photoshop for batch exporting JPG to DDS, but I couldn't do this. Here's what I've tried to do using Photoshop:
Open Photoshop -> Window -> Actions -> Create new action -> Name = 'dds' -> Record -> File -> Open -> I go to the folder "dir" which contains several images: 1.jpg, 2.jg, ... , 4.jpg and choose "1.jpg" -> I press "OK" in the "Missing profile" window where the "Leave as is" option is chosen by default -> File -> Save a Copy -> I choose the DDS format without changing the file name -> Save -> in the DDS options I set "Format = DXT1", "Alpha channel = None" -> OK -> Stop playing/recording. Then I go File -> Automate -> Batch -> Action = dds -> Source = Folder, I choose "dir" ->  I unset four checkboxes below -> Destination = Folder -> I choose "dir". I leave all other parameters unchanged and press "OK". Then I click "OK" four times on the "Missing profile" window. After all this I have five pictures in the "dir" folder: 1 copy.dds, 1.jpg, 2.jg, ... , 4.jpg.
The only way I see is a GIMP script, but I'm not familiar with it at all.
Any other methods will suit me if they give output DDS files like after Photoshop/GIMP conversion with size 128 KB (or close to this size). It seems to be BC1/DXT1.

"I've tried to create an action for Photoshop for batch exporting JPG to DDS, but I couldn't do this." Why? What happens when you try to run the action as a batch?

@cybernetic.nomad, it didn't save output DDS images in the directories where original JPG pictures came from. I just applyed an action to a directory with subdirectories. Also, I had to press "OK" on the DDS setting window options for every picture converting. And in general the Photoshop conversion by this way (through an action) is not very convenient since I need to convert thousands of pictures. But maybe I just do something wrong.

Hello, "I tried X/Y/Z" without showing any accurate source and results of X, Y, Z is not a good idea here. It's basically as if you didn't mention those. You should be way more detailed and e.g. show the script's code + mention the exact results.

@Destroy666, sorry, what script do you mean? For ImageMagick?

For anything that you mentioned.

Sorry, now I've understood what you mean by X, Y, Z. Could I edit my started post to describe my attempts and results?

Editing your post is strongly recommended on this site. Please read the HELP section to better understand how this site works. Edit your question as often as necessary to add information and to improve the question.
